# Car parked behind my car blocking exit

Tags: vehicle, parking

I live on the first floor of a house in Connecticut with neighbors in different floors. We share the same parking lot which has a reasonable amount of parking spots. The problem is, this one neighbor keeps parking behind a car and blocking the way out. One time, her car was parked behind mine and I couldn't take my car to school in the morning (I'm employed by the school so I make my income there for what it's worth.).

I really hope there's a way I can rectify this situation legally because this has been happening way too frequently. Can I have her car towed or is there any authority I can report to? Attached is a photo that shows what keeps happening.

[image]

Comment: I assume the parking lot belongs the building, and that it is likely that both you and the neighbor are tenants?  Assuming this is the case, does the lease state anything about parking?

Comment: If it is a tenant, is there space for her to not block someone? Can the trash cans be moved (it looks like there might be space for another car then)?

Comment: Can you back out diagonal between her car and the white car, maybe with the recycling bins moved? Can you knock on her door when it’s time for you to leave? In any case, this appears to be off the street so the police will not ticket or tow her. If she was trespassing (she is not, bc she is also a tenant) then your building owner might be allowed to have her towed by a private company. Probably would require a sign “parking for residents only, violators will be towed.” Of course we don’t know your town ordinances bc we don’t know the town.

Comment: Difficult to judge accurately from the angle of the photo, but it really does seem that you didn't need to leave such a large gap between your car and the white one - in which case the driver of the car behind yours probably feels that you've brought this situation on yourself by preventing them from parking next to you...